# Using table join and update in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, attribute-joins

I decided to completely restructure the code I was using for my ingest/QAQC script that I am building. I managed to get around using a table join for the first QA/QC part, but this part may require the join. Here's my code block.

```
    def findRevisit():      #Looks for revisited in the incoming data set using table join and DT(date) field. Flags potential revisits with '2' in QAQC_FLAG field.
        arcpy.env.workspace = inPGDB
        rtTbl = "midFCviewJoin_vw"
        leftTbl = in_table_view
        joinField = "UUID"
        dateField = "DT"
        updField = "QAQC_FLAG"
        fields = [joinField,dateField,updField]
        leftDate = in_table + "." + dateField
        rtDate = midFCview+ "." + dateField
        arcpy.AddJoin_management(leftTbl,joinField,rtTbl,joinField)
    ##    arcpy.JoinField_management(leftTbl,joinField,rtTbl,joinField,"")
        sql = leftTbl + "." + joinField + " <> " + rtTbl + "." + joinField
        print "SQL where clause: " + sql
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(leftTbl,[dateField,updField],sql) as cursor:
            for rec in cursor:
                rec[1]=2    ##Set QAQC flag = 2 for possible revisits in the incoming dataset
                cursor.updateRow(rec)
                print rec
    ##    arcpy.DeleteField_management(in_table, "QAQC_FLAG_1")
        arcpy.RemoveJoin_management(leftTbl)
        return leftTbl,rtTbl,sql
        del cursor,rec
```

Seems like it should run. Both table views are in the same workspace. It still falls on its face. Here is the error I get from the cursor:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/kgaines/Documents/Aquadat/Scripting/AquaDat_tableCreate_findDup_findRevisit_defFunct.py", line 232, in <module>
main()
      File "C:/Users/kgaines/Documents/Aquadat/Scripting/AquaDat_tableCreate_findDup_findRevisit_defFunct.py", line 225, in main
findRevisit()
      File "C:/Users/kgaines/Documents/Aquadat/Scripting/AquaDat_tableCreate_findDup_findRevisit_defFunct.py", line 169, in findRevisit
for rec in cursor:
      RuntimeError: Too few parameters. Expected 2.
```

Where is the "Too few parameters" error coming from?

Here are a couple of images showing the field names in the in_table. All of the other tables and views have exactly the same fields.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Try defining the the fields like this: "fields  = [dateField,updField]" or more explicitly if you can as "fields = ['DT', 'QAQC_FLAG'] prior to calling it in UpdateCursor.

Comment: Still gives the too few parameters error. I don't get it. This should work! Grrrr!!!!

Comment: Are **dateField** and **updField** part of **leftTbl**? or are they part of **rtTbl**? If latter as I suspect, the problem is that after joining the tables the joins are not recognized by UpdateCursor, so that's why it is throwing an error saying that it requires two arguments. I think you want to save/export the joined table and then perform UpdateCursor.

Comment: dateField and updField actually belong to both tables. The tables share a common field design.


I am starting to think that the join isn't going to work in this form. I may have to use some other method to pull out the UUIDs of records that meet the search criteria and use those to update the master in_table before creating the XY layer and outFC.

Comment: I think you need to to include UUID as a field in the UpdateCursor as well and double your SQL syntax as well. I'm including a modified script below. Hopefully that'll help.

Answer (score 1):

```
    def findRevisit():
        arcpy.env.workspace = inPGDB
        r_Table = "midFCviewJoin_vw"
        l_Table_view = in_table_view
        arcpy.MakeTableView_management(r_Table, r_Table_view) #assuming that the left table is already 'table view'

        #Joining Tables
        arcpy.AddJoin_management(l_Table_view, "UUID", r_Table_view, "UUID")

        #Create a table view out of joined tables
        arcpy.MakeTableView_management(l_Table_view, joined_table)

        fields = ["UUID", "DT", "QAQC_FLAG"]
        sql = '"UUID" <> "UUID"'

        #Here I assume you are saying: Change DT value to 2 
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(joined_table, fields, sql) as cursor:
            for rec in cursor:
                rec[1] = 2 ##Set QAQC flag = 2 for possible revisits in the incoming dataset
                cursor.updateRow(rec)
                print rec

        arcpy.RemoveJoin_management(joined_table)
        return l_Table_view, r_Table_view, sql
        del cursor, rec
```